# Equivalent definition of order of element in group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was just reviewing basic group and startlingly was not able to prove a simple statement.

Suppose that $G$ is a group and $a\in G$. Consider $\langle a\rangle:=\{a^k: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ a cyclic group generated by $a$. Consider the following two definitions of *order of element*.

**Definition 1.** $\text{ord}(a):=|\langle a\rangle|$.

**Definition 2.** $\text{ord}(a):=\min \{k\in \mathbb{N}:a^k=e\}$. If there is no such $k$, then we assume that $\text{ord}(a)=\infty$.

I want to prove that these definitions are equivalent.

*Proof:* Definition 2 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 1.

1. Suppose that there is no such $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^k=e$, i.e. $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a^k\neq e$. It immediately follows that $|\langle a\rangle|=\infty$. Otherwise, there are $k<l$ such that $a^k=a^l$ which leads to the contradiction.
2. Let $p$ is the least natural such that $a^p=e$. We'll show that $|\langle a\rangle|=p$. By division algorithm easy to check that $\langle a \rangle=\{a^i\}_{i=0}^{p-1}$ and elements in the RHS set are pairwise distinct. Hence $|\langle a \rangle|=p$.

Definition 1 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 2.

1. Let $|\langle a \rangle|=\infty$, then there is no such $k\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $a^k=e$. Otherwise, we would obtain that $|\langle a \rangle|<\infty$.
2. If $|\langle a \rangle|<\infty$ and $|\langle a \rangle|=n$ how to prove that $n=\min \{k\in \mathbb{N}: a^k=e\}$? I have issues with this part.

I tried some ideas but they did not work out!
Thank you!

Comment: If $\langle a \rangle$ has cardinality $n$ then among the elements $\{ 1, a, a^2, \dots a^n \}$ some two of them must be the same by pigeonhole, say $a^i = a^j$. So $a^{i-j} = e$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, We have that $a^{j-i}=e$ for $0<j-i\leq n$. Let $p:=j-i$ and we see that $a^p=e$ with $0<p\leq n$. If $p<n$, then $|\langle a\rangle|\leq p$ and hence $p=n$. It follows that $\min \{k\in \mathbb{N}:a^k=e\}\leq n$. Easy to show that $\min \{k\in \mathbb{N}:a^k=e\}=n$ otherwise we would get that $|\langle a\rangle|<n$ which is a contradiction.